# Ender 3 S1 Pro – Z offset keeps changing

Tags: creality-ender-3, z-axis, klipper

I have recently bought an Ender 3 S1 Pro and it has been a bit of a hit and miss so far. My main problem has been the Z offset. It keeps changing between prints. The first print turns out okay and then when I print the same thing again it just breaks.

I followed the steps for method one from

to level the X axis gantry which made things much better. For a while. But just recently a print failed after about half an hour. It seemed like the printer got the Z-offset wrong because the layers just wouldn't stick any more. I aborted the print and did a height map calibration:
[image: Height map calibration]
And this how it went. The printer also made some stuttering sounds when probing the plate at the far right.

I'm using Klipper with MainsailOS instead of the stock firmware. I have updated everything to the latest available version.

It seems like I need to make some adjustments, but I'm not sure what to do. Should I try to adjust the X-gantry again? I have levelled the bed and the four corners are pretty much level. I'm also using [this model](https://www.printables.com/model/251587-stress-free-first-layer-calibration-in-less-than-5) to get a good enough first layer. And that works, but only for one print. Then I have to redo the Z-offset calibration as well as perform the height map calibration. I don't think I should have to do that every time? The printer is placed in a stable location and I'm not moving it between prints. I also clean the bed with IPA before each print. And I have a PEI plate.

So I'm wondering what I should try to to adjust/tweak/calibrate to get the printer to work reliably?

Answer (score 1):

Try tightening the eccentric nuts on the Y carriage, they were lose on mine from factory which was causing it to rock side-to-side so made bed leveling impossible.